# How to solve a parameteric linear equation in Zn?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given monoid ($\Bbb{Z}$124, ⋅ ) and a parametric equation with parameter $a$ where

$ax+2=5(x+a)-1$

Give the number of parameters $a$ belong $\Bbb{Z}$124 for which the above equation has precisely one solution ?

i tried to solve it by using the euclidean algorithm but i dont know how to calculate it with the parameter $a$

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange to $(a-5)x=5a-3$, and note that this has a unique solution if and only if the coefficient in front of $x$, which is $a-5$, is coprime with $124$. How many such numbers are there?

Comment: gcd(124,a-5)=1, so how are we going to solve it with the parameter?

Comment: @jason That's not what the parameter $a$ means. It means that this is a template for $124$ different equations. The first equation is $(1-5)x=5\cdot1 -3$, the second one is $(2-5)x=5\cdot 2-3$, and so on. The problem is to tell hour many of these equations has one unique solution.

Comment: And how can we find a such that the equation has a unique solution?

Comment: @jason That's what I said in my answer: iff the coefficient in front of $x$ is coprime with $124$ then the equation has a unique solution. For the first equation that number is $-4$, so that's a no-go. For the second one the coefficient is $-3$, so that one _does_ have a unique solution. And so on.

Comment: how can i find a general expression for a ?